# visibilitychange gets called multiple times if using fullscreen api

Tags: javascript, fullscreen, visibility, visibilitychange

I am using `visibilitychange` event of browser. All looks good.

After clicking on one of my buttons, I use `fullScreen API` to take website into fullscreen mode.

The issue that I have is `visibilitychange` event gets called twice when getting into `fullscreen` mode and when I exit fullscreen mode, `visibilitychange` gets called 4 times . Is there any reason why this is happening? Isn't there any way that it will only get called once ?

```
this.visibility = () => {
          console.log("this gets called multiple times ");
}
document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', this.visibility, false);
```

Comment: Can you show what the code looks like or provide a reproducible example of your code?

Comment: Could you be listening more than once to the event? It sounds like `addEventListener` multiplicity.

Comment: updated the example.